# Parsing multiple routes from within single path

Tags: angular, routes, angular4-router

I have a problem in Angular4, where multiple users will be accessing the path '', and I want my routes to redirect them to the correct component based on access.

These are my routes, however only the first one is considered:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'main',
    },
    {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: '(primary:dashboard)',
                data: {
                    permission: PERMISSION_DASHBOARD,
                },
                canActivate: [PermissionGuard],
            },
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: '(primary:custory)',
                data: {
                    permission: PERMISSION_CUSTODY_TRANSFER,
                },
                canActivate: [PermissionGuard],
            },
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                outlet: 'primary',
                component: DashComponent,
                data: {
                    permission: PERMISSION_DASHBOARD,
                },
                canActivate: [PermissionGuard],
            },
            {
                path: 'custory',
                outlet: 'primary',
                component: CustodyComponent,
                data: {
                    permission: PERMISSION_CUSTODY_TRANSFER,
                },
                canActivate: [PermissionGuard],
            }
        ]
    },
];
```

In the example above, only the first child from path main is evaluated, however, i need to evaluate both.

Comment: you could remove the redirectTo from the first child and handle your redirecting logic in a canActivate guard

Comment: my canActivate is already implemented, how can I handle the redirection within the guard itself?

Comment: within the guard you would determine where they should be redirected then do `Router.navigate(...); return false;`

Comment: canActivate does not have the router object as its constructor:

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):

Comment: you can inject whatever you need within your guard's contructor

Comment: I'm sorta new to angular: can you take a look :  

class permission guard :  
@Injectable()
export class PermissionGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private store: Store<RootState>, private router: Router) {

    }

that is within another module  for security

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    providers: [
        PermissionGuard,
    ],
    ...
})
export class SecurityModule { }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158428/discussion-between-llai-and-danilo-silva).